# Angularjs ng-repeat use key as property name of an obj

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In angular, I would like to use    key  of a ng-repeat  as a property name of an obj

```
            $scope.datas= {};
            $scope.datas.key1 = 'val1';
            $scope.datas.key2 = 'val2';


             $scope.dictionnary= {};
             $scope.dictionnary['key1']  ='toto';
             $scope.dictionnary['key2']  ='titi';


    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in datas">
    {{dictionnary[key]}} //does not work!
    </div>
```

Do you know hot to do this?

Comment: both datas and displaysrc are arrays, did you mean to use displaysrc as a dictionary ? i.e for 'key1' => 'toto'

Comment: yes i am using displaysrc  as a dictionnary, i changed name

Comment: so it whouldnt be an array it should be a key value object like so `{key1: 'toto'}` and then you can access 'toto' by using `dictionnary['key1']`

Comment: you are right, thx

Comment: Seems, the structure is the issue. http://jsbin.com/nayosi/1/edit?html,js,console,output this would be better if you need more or less flat structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it may come down to a few things:

**1:**
you can use datas also as a dictionary and then it would work with 1 loop (**PICK ME**)

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.datas = {};
    $scope.datas.key1 = 'val1';
    $scope.datas.key2 = 'val2';


    $scope.dictionnary = {};
    $scope.dictionnary['key1'] = 'toto';
    $scope.dictionnary['key2'] = 'titi';
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in datas">
      {{dictionnary[key]}} //does not work!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2**: you can use nested ng-repeat like @Omri Aharon showed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for all objects you would need 2 ng-repeats here, one to iterate over your array, and the other one to fetch the key from the object you are now iterating on:

```
    <div ng-repeat="data in datas">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
        {{key}}
      </div>   
    </div>
```

Note that here you already have the object as data, so if you explained your problem we could suggest maybe a different approach.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6502/)